# Abstracting/generecizing class hierarchy variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have several classes and I want each one to maintain on the class level a hash of all the instances that have been created for future lookup. Something akin to:

```
class A
  def initialize(id, otherstuff)
    # object creation logic
    @@my_hash[id]=self
  end

  def self.find(id)
    @@my_hash[id]
  end
end
```

so I can then `A.find(id)` and get the right instance back.

There are several of these classes (A, B, etc), all having ids, all of which I want to have this functionality.

Can I have them all inherit from a superclass which has a generic version of this which they can leverage so I don't have to reimplement many things for every class?

Comment: if you are trying to keep track of scope then you dont need a hash to store the self, you can use ancestor method, or you can directly use object.class

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can either inherit from the same superclass, or use modules and `include`:

```
module M
  def initialize(id)
    @@all ||= {}
    @@all[id] = self
  end

  def print
    p @@all
  end
end

class C
  include M
  def initialize(id)
    super
    puts "C instantiated"
  end
end
```

If you want to keep separate indexes for each subclass, you can do something like:

```
def initialize(id)
  @@all ||= {}
  @@all[self.class] ||= {}
  @@all[self.class][id] = self
end
```

Edit: After your comment, I see that you need to keep per-class indexes. So:

```
class A
  def initialize(id)
    self.class.index(id, self)
  end

  def self.index id, instance
    @all ||= {}
    @all[id] = instance
  end

  def self.find(id)
    @all[id]
  end
end

class B < A
end

class C < A
end

a = A.new(1)
b = B.new(2)
c = C.new(3)
p A.find(1)
#=> #<A:0x10016c190>
p B.find(2)
#=> #<B:0x10016c140>
p C.find(3)
#=> #<C:0x10016c118>
p A.find(2)
#=> nil
```

Comment: It seems like I still have to put stuff in every class. Is there a way I can define everything in M - the thing to hash the instance and the find function (and all function), so then I can do A.all and get all A instances, B.find(id) and get the instance of B with the given id, etc.

Comment: The only thing you have to do in every class is call `super` in the constructor. Not sure if that is a dealbreaker for you. See the latest edit btw.